# When developing Silverlight apps is it ok to just to run directly from the test page?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

When I create a new Silverlight project in Visual Studio it creates a new web project in the same solution and wires it up to run in a local server when developing and debugging.

Some demo projects I have downloaded just run directly from the test page on disk. When **developing** what are the benefits of running via a server? What would you lose by just running from the disk?

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Silverlight app is "standalone", that is it does not need to make WCF, Web service calls or other http requests back to the server then simply running from the test htm is fine, you don't need a host web app or site.